Are there any ways to get around the 60kb limit for Anchor IDL initialization?
Want to upload the idl to a large program, is there anyway to either increase the max from 60kb or compress the idl size?

I didnt know there was such a limit. Maybe you can open an issue and ask if its possible to increase the limit: https://github.com/coral-xyz/anchor

The limit is well over 60kb. The max program size is ~1.25 MB.
If you have already deployed the program the easiest solution is to redeploy: anchor allocates double the initial size of your idl for upgrades. There are also ways to increase the size of your program buffer after deployment but they are more complex than deploying.
You don't even need to upload the idl: you can set default = ["no-idl"] with no-idl = [] to skip it if you want to save space.

Yeah I meant specifically onchain IDL size, not the program itself, I had to modify the anchor CLI directly (there's a check in the init instruction). Not sure what the onchain limit would be.

I think it uses the same buffer space for the idl, so the overall program size limit includes the IDL. There's also a practical limit in getting off so many txes to get an upgrade through once the size gets to a certain point but that's another story.
